# Finding chemical equilibrium with an application to the Sun

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, ideal-gas, stars

Consider the following reversible reaction: $\rm H_{2}{\rightleftharpoons}2H$. To find chemical equilibrium, we use the chemical equilibrium constant. There are two equations for the chemical equilibrium constant. The first is,

K$_{\rm eq}$ = $\frac{[H]^{2}}{[H_{2}]}=\frac{f_{H}^{2}}{f_{H_{2}}}P_{T}=\frac{f_{H}^{2}}{1-f_{H}}P_{T}$,

where $f$ is the mole fraction of a species and $P_{T}$ is the total pressure of the gas. The second equation is,

K$_{\rm eq}$ = $P_{0} \exp{\left(-\frac{\Delta G_{0}}{RT}\right)}$,

where $P_{0}$ is the standard pressure (1 bar), $\Delta G_{0}$ is the standard Gibbs free energy of formation, $R$ is the ideal gas constant, and $T$ is the temperature. Combining the two equations,

$\frac{f_{H}^{2}}{1-f_{H}} = \frac{P_{0}}{P_{T}} \exp{\left(-\frac{\Delta G_{0}}{RT}\right)}$.

The problem I have with this equation is that it predicts that the Sun's photosphere is mostly molecular hydrogen ($T\sim 5800$ K, $P\sim 0.1$ bar, and $\Delta G_{0}=436$kJ per mol). Could someone explain why this grossly underestimates the mole fraction of H of the photosphere? I understand that I assumed a pure hydrogen gas so that $1-f_{H_{2}}=f_{H}$, but I am unsure that this is the cause. Is the equation correct?

Comment: *"The problem I have with this equation is that it predicts that the Sun's photosphere is mostly molecular hydrogen."* How do you arrive at that conclusion? I.e. what numbers are you using?

Comment: The photosphere of the sun has a temperature and pressure of about T~5800 K and P~10^4 Pa. The standard gibbs free energy is 436*10^3 J mol^-1. Plugging these values into the above equation leads to fH^2/(1-fH)~10^-3, which leads to  fH~3*10^-2.

In any case, is the above equation correct?

Comment: The formula is correct, I think (from memory) but I don't think you can use the **standard Gibbs Free Energy.

Comment: So you reckon I should use the temperature dependent Gibbs free energy instead? Would you know of any sources for this?

Comment: Yes, you need to adjust your GFE for temperature. Have a look at this: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Physical_Chemistry_for_the_Biosciences_(Chang)/04%3A_The_Second_Law_of_Thermodynamics/4.08%3A_Dependence_of_Gibbs_Energy_on_Temperature_and_Pressure#:~:text=Gibbs%20free%20energy%2C%20denoted%20G,and%20entropy%20of%20the%20system.

Comment: I disagree. If you look at 4.8.11 of the document you sent it says that in equilibrium ΔG=0, so only ΔG0 (standard state) matters.

Comment: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Equilibria/Le_Chateliers_Principle/Effect_Of_Temperature_On_Equilibrium_Composition